# Upgrading to MSAL Missing AUD in JWT token

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

I am setting up a move to MSAL but the JWT token is missing the aud:
This is a WPF desktop app calling into a web api (ASP.Net)

```
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()                
            .Build();
```

I have set the scope to the to match the scope set up in the webapi (app registration)

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/access_as_user" };
```

then call

```
var accounts = await App.PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
                AuthenticationResult authResult;
                try
                {
                    authResult = await App.PublicClientApp
                        .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    authResult = await App.PublicClientApp
                        .AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)                           
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
```

The JWT token coming back always is missing the aud:

[image: Missing aud]

Then I call a simple test to see if the code will work.

```
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
                var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, "https://****.azurewebsites.net/api/Combo/getComboList");                    
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I always get an error;
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
Any pointer would be gratefully accepted.
Thanks

EDIT:
Here is a screen shot of the delegated permissions. On the Native client app under App Registration. 
[image]

Comment: Have you registered 2 Applications one for the client application and other for the api. Then on the client app registration you need to give delegated access permission to the registered application for the web api. "aud" is the protected resource in your case its  the web api. If you are not getting that back in the token, it means your app registration setup is incorrect. Have another look at the resources you used to register applications. Share the screenshots of app registration.

Comment: Thanks rohit. Screenshot added above. I believe the delegated permissions are set up correctly. Login does not fail when using the scopes. It was only that I was comparing the JWT token between a system that works (ADAL) and new MSAL and notice the aud: was blank. I have not upgraded the manifest to 2. "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,

Comment: and yes, 2 application have been set up. One native and one web api.

Comment: Delegated permissions appear to be fine.I am confused. In your question you say you get permission denied but now you say login does not fail. What is the issue then?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. The bearer token comes back to me fine (aud is blank though) but as I call to the web api, I get 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page'. I can run the same call, into the api via the old ADAL call and can confirm the data comes back fine.

Comment: OK. What is identity provider in your case? Is it AD or ADB2C ? There are some difference between ADAL and MSAL. Have a read through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-compare-msal-js-and-adal-js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214408/discussion-between-rohit-and-scottsanpedro).

Comment: sure. that would be good. I have a report to get out now. I will contact you after that. thanks so much